# How long will Firefox 3.6 be supported for those who choose not to upgrade?

Tags: firefox-3.6

How long will Firefox 3.6 be supported for those who choose not to upgrade to versions 4 or later?

Answer (score 1):

For now, all Mozilla has said is that it'll be supported "[for a short amount of time](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1050&bih=1596&q=firefox+3.6+end+of+life&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=)."

It's worth noting that Firefox 4, like FF3.5 and all other older versions, is already past EOL.

Wikipedia has [a table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Release_history) with support status, too.